# ffmpeg running in cloudfunction silently fails/never finishes

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement a Cloudfunction which would run `ffmpeg` on a Google bucket upload. I have been playing with a script based on https://kpetrovi.ch/2017/11/02/transcoding-videos-with-ffmpeg-in-google-cloud-functions.html

The original script needs little tuning as the library evolved a bit. My current version is here:

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpeg_static = require('ffmpeg-static');

console.log("Linking ffmpeg path to:", ffmpeg_static)
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static);

exports.transcodeVideo = (event, callback) => {
    const bucket = storage.bucket(event.bucket);
    console.log(event);
    if (event.name.indexOf('uploads/') === -1) {
        console.log("File " + event.name + " is not to be processed.")
        return;
    }

    // ensure that you only proceed if the file is newly createdxxs
    if (event.metageneration !== '1') {
        callback();
        return;
    }

    // Open write stream to new bucket, modify the filename as needed.
    const targetName = event.name.replace("uploads/", "").replace(/[.][a-z0-9]+$/, "");
    console.log("Target name will be: " + targetName);

    const remoteWriteStream = bucket.file("processed/" + targetName + ".mp4")
        .createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                //metadata: event.metadata, // You may not need this, my uploads have associated metadata
                contentType: 'video/mp4', // This could be whatever else you are transcoding to
            },
        });

    // Open read stream to our uploaded file
    const remoteReadStream = bucket.file(event.name).createReadStream();

    // Transcode
    ffmpeg()
        .input(remoteReadStream)
        .outputOptions('-c:v copy') // Change these options to whatever suits your needs
        .outputOptions('-c:a aac')
        .outputOptions('-b:a 160k')
        .outputOptions('-f mp4')
        .outputOptions('-preset fast')
        .outputOptions('-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov')
        // https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/346#issuecomment-67299526
        .on('start', (cmdLine) => {
            console.log('Started ffmpeg with command:', cmdLine);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Successfully re-encoded video.');
            callback();
        })
        .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.error('An error occured during encoding', err.message);
            console.error('stdout:', stdout);
            console.error('stderr:', stderr);
            callback(err);
        })
        .pipe(remoteWriteStream, { end: true }); // end: true, emit end event when readable stream ends
};
```

This version correctly runs and I can see this in logs:

```
2020-06-16 21:24:22.606  Function execution took 912 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
2020-06-16 21:24:52.902  Started ffmpeg with command: ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 160k -f mp4 -preset fast -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov pipe:1
```

It seems the function execution ends before the actual ffmpeg command, which then never finishes.

Is there a way to make the ffmpeg "synchronous" or "blocking" so that it finishes before the function execution?

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong in your code.  Please edit the question to show an MCVE with the code that isn't working the way you expect. Don't share links to external code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you share the code where this behavior may originate? This will help to understand better this scenario

Comment: The code was there within the gist aleady. I extracted the part which seems to cause the problem and put it directly within the question.

Comment: You're probably not dealing with promises correctly. Without seeing the code for the *entire* function, we still can't see if you're doing something wrong in the context of Cloud Functions.  Questions on Stack Overflow should contain the *entire* code within the question itself.  External links can go bad, which makes the question unhelpful to others in the future.

Comment: I added the full code, however the link was there and working.

Comment: You're not returning a promise that resolves when all the work is complete.  This is an obligation for all Cloud Functions code that are not HTTP.  Without that, Cloud Functions will clean up immediately and your work will not finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background) it seems the function should accept three arguments: `(data, context, callback)` have you tried this or do you know that `context` is optional? From the docs it seems that if the function accepts three arguments is treated as a background function, if it accepts only two arguments, is treated as a background function only if it returns a `Promise`.

More than this some other point:

1: here no `callback` function is called, if in your tests your function exited with that log line, it is another point suggesting that calling the second argument as a callback function is a required step to make process finish:

```
if (event.name.indexOf('uploads/') === -1) {
    console.log("File " + event.name + " is not to be processed.")
    return;
}
```

2. I would suggest to add some other `console.log` (or many other, if you prefer) to clarify the flow: in your question you pasted only 1 log line, it is not so much helpful more to say it is logged after the system log line
3. the link you used as tutorial is almost three years old, it could be that google cloud has changed its interface in the mean while.

Once said that, if acceptint three arguments rather than only two doesn't solve your problem, you can try changing your function in a `Promise`:

```
exports.transcodeVideo = (event, callback) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const bucket = storage.bucket(event.bucket);
    console.log(event);
    if (event.name.indexOf('uploads/') === -1) {
        console.log("File " + event.name + " is not to be processed.")
        return resolve(); // or reject if this is an error case
    }

    // ensure that you only proceed if the file is newly createdxxs
    if (event.metageneration !== '1') {
        return resolve(); // or reject if this is an error case
    }

    // Open write stream to new bucket, modify the filename as needed.
    const targetName = event.name.replace("uploads/", "").replace(/[.][a-z0-9]+$/, "");
    console.log("Target name will be: " + targetName);

    const remoteWriteStream = bucket.file("processed/" + targetName + ".mp4")
        .createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                //metadata: event.metadata, // You may not need this, my uploads have associated metadata
                contentType: 'video/mp4', // This could be whatever else you are transcoding to
            },
        });

    // Open read stream to our uploaded file
    const remoteReadStream = bucket.file(event.name).createReadStream();

    // Transcode
    ffmpeg()
        .input(remoteReadStream)
        .outputOptions('-c:v copy') // Change these options to whatever suits your needs
        .outputOptions('-c:a aac')
        .outputOptions('-b:a 160k')
        .outputOptions('-f mp4')
        .outputOptions('-preset fast')
        .outputOptions('-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov')
        // https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/346#issuecomment-67299526
        .on('start', (cmdLine) => {
            console.log('Started ffmpeg with command:', cmdLine);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Successfully re-encoded video.');
            resolve();
        })
        .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.error('An error occured during encoding', err.message);
            console.error('stdout:', stdout);
            console.error('stderr:', stderr);
            reject(err);
        })
        .pipe(remoteWriteStream, { end: true }); // end: true, emit end event when readable stream ends
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just for complement this answer I suggest your take a look at on this document where is pointed when you create a background task you must finish or resolve these tasks before returning from the function, this applies to the promise too.

When you return a JavaScript promise to a function, that function keeps running until the promise is resolved or rejected. To indicate that a function has completed its work successfully, the promise should be resolved.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background

Comment: The part with `=> new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` helped. Thanks! I am not yet able to award you the bounty, it says I can do that in 6 hours.

Comment: I can wait :) Thank you for have accepted the answer. But moreover I'm happy you solved your problem